# Windows 8.1 app always stop running at StartPeriodicUpdateBatch

Tags: c#, windows-8, winrt-xaml, windows-8.1

I use tile update for my windows 8.1 app. It had well run before, but today, my app always stop at StartPeriodicUpdateBatch

Here is my code:

```
        TileUpdater tileUpdater = TileUpdateManager.CreateTileUpdaterForApplication();
        tileUpdater.EnableNotificationQueue(true);

        Uri[] uris = new Uri[5];
        uris[0] = new Uri(tileUrl1);
        uris[1] = new Uri(tileUrl2);
        uris[2] = new Uri(tileUrl3);
        uris[3] = new Uri(tileUrl4);
        uris[4] = new Uri(tileUrl5);
        tileUpdater.StartPeriodicUpdateBatch(uris, PeriodicUpdateRecurrence.HalfHour);
```

Here is a return of urls:

```
<tile>
     <visual>
          <binding template="TileWideImageAndText01">
               <image id="1" src="http://media.baotintuc.vn/2014/02/27/16/09/nha-truyen-giao.jpg" alt="alt text"/>
               <text id="1">
                 Text
          </text>
         </binding>
         <binding template="TileSquarePeekImageAndText04">
             <image id="1" src="http://media.baotintuc.vn/2014/02/27/16/09/nha-truyen-giao.jpg" alt="alt text"/>
            <text id="1">
                 Text
            </text>
        </binding>
     </visual>
   </tile>
```

Comment: Where is this code from? You should call `StartPeriodicUpdateBatch` when the application starts up or resumes.

Comment: I call it when the app starts up at App.xaml.cs

Comment: `Uri[] uris = new Uri[1];` Did you mean `Uri[] uris = new Uri[5];`?

Comment: Yes: Uri[] uris = new Uri[5];